# Injecting a dependency into a library class not managed by spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am pretty new to spring or dependency injection. I have an abstract class A in a jar file built already, which is not managed by Spring (This is based on the fact that it does not have any of its dependencies auto-wired, no spring annotations used in the library.).

I have project which needs to use this class and want to inject my implementations of class A's dependency (say, of Type B). This project uses springboot.

How can I inject dependency of type B into A?
I tried following : 
1. Created a configuration (@Configuration) class and added a method getB() annotated as @Bean which will return object of type B using my implementation of B.

```
@Bean
public B getB () {
   return new MyB();
}
```

Comment: You means that you want **(1)** to inject `B` in `A` so that you can use `A` in your code. Or **(2)** use/inject `B` which is a subclass of `A` in you project ?

Comment: I want to inject B into A. I have created an implementation MyB of interface B, which I want to inject in A. A is an abstract class which holds field of type B and both A and B are in a jar which is already built.

Comment: Then see my answer below, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48058011/1632752)

Comment: And if one answer is okay, please mark your question as answered

Comment: Yup, accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to inject `B` into `A` you cannot. Since `A` is not managed by Spring, the IOC container will never inject anything in a class that he does not know.

The key to your problem is the way you want to get and use the instance of `A`.

If you want to use `A` in your code managed by spring then you have to create yourself a factory for `A` :

```
@Bean
public A a() {
    B b = new MyB();
    A a = new A(b); // new A is not possible since A is abstract but you got the idea
    return a;
}

// ...

class MyService {
   @Autowired
   A a;

   void something() {
      (a.b instanceof MyB) // true
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked.